# Getting the selected value from radio buttons into the database

Tags: java, jquery, html, sqlplus

So I have an html table, and I am using a particular cell's value in each row to generate an array (using .split("")) and then for each value in the array, I am generating radio buttons using the code provided in a dialog box.

Where I am stuck as of now is: How can I get the value of the selected radio button [multiple selections are allowed], and submit this value to the database.

I have provided the code which I am using the get the cell value from the current row, as well the code which I am using to generate the radio buttons. 
I am newbie so please don't mind if something sounds stupid. I am just trying to find my way to learning.

I am sorry if I am not able to explain the problem. I am trying my best.

Thanks.

I have tried using [alert :checked] but nothing comes up. I have not have had much luck coming up with logic / workflows on my own and would love to have a direction.

```
 $(".dialogbox").click(function(){
            $('#divid').dialog('open');
            var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    
            var $text= $row.find(".reqcell").text();
            var valarray = new Array();
            valarray = $text.split(",");

## Here (".dialogbox") is the class of a button which when clicked open a dialog which has a div with id = '#divid'. I am using the this.closest(tr) to find the closest row to the button clicked, and then find the cell (whose values are needed), using the class name (".reqcell") for the class.
In the end I use text.split(",") to store these values into an array valarray. ##
```

```
## The below code is in continuation to the above mentioned code . I am just dividing it for the ease of understanding.


var buttons = valarray.filter(Boolean).map((valarray,index) => {

            return '<input type="radio" value='+ index +' name='+ valarray +'/><label for='+ valarray +'>'+ valarray +'</label>';
            });
            $("#buttonArea").html(buttons.join(""));});


## Here button area refers to the <span> in which the buttons will be displayed.
```

As I said before, I have to get the value of selected button/buttons and update it in the database. 
If anyone can give me any kind of direction for the same , I will be really obliged.

And again, I am very sorry if the way I am trying to explain things is wrong.

Also, if someone could suggest some good books to learn Java (including the database connections and client-server web-apps building) and jQuery, it will be great.

Thank you everyone for your time.!

Comment: for radio buttons, names should be same and values changes, but in this case you have radio buttons with different names and values. you should use checkbox

Comment: Hello Alex, 

Thank you so much for your input. I can change the input type from radio to checkbox, However I still do not understand the logic of getting the selected value of the checkbox and storing it in the database. I will be very grateful if you can please give me a direction as to where / what  I should look for. Thanks!

Comment: Since the radio buttons are being injected after the DOM was initially rendered, you might look at the [jQuery `.on()` method](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to trap the user clicks. [See this](https://api.jquery.com/on/).  Then use AJAX to send the information to your back-end processing file, which will receive the data and schlep it into the database.

Comment: Hello cssyphus, Thanks for the input. 
However, I am confused as what selector do I use in the .on() for the specific button which is selected. If possible could you implement a fiddle. Thanks.